# Memory Leaks in Python with C API

Tags: python, c

I'm trying to integrate a few C functions that I have written into Python and I am running into some issues.

Here is my code

```
static PyObject*
FOO(PyObject *self,PyObject *args, PyObject *keywds)
{

int numItems;
PyObject *data_in;
PyObject *data_out;  
PyObject *itemObj;

int bytesPerItem = 1
uint8_t  data[8][544];  

static char    *kwlist[] = {"data_in","data_out", NULL};

if (!PyArg_ParseTupleAndKeywords(args, keywds, "O!O!",
                                 kwlist, &PyList_Type, &data_in, &PyList_Type, &data_out)
{
    return NULL;
}

 if (!PyList_Size(data_in))
 {
    PyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "Invalid Data Buffer Size");
    return NULL;
 }
 else
 {
    numItems = PyList_Size(data_in);
 }
int i;
for (i=0; i < numItems*bytesPerItem; i += bytesPerItem)
{
    itemObj = PyList_GetItem(data_in, i/bytesPerItem);
    if (!itemObj)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    switch (bytesPerItem)
    {
        case 1:

             *(*(data)+i) =PyLong_AsUnsignedLong(itemObj) & 0xFF;
             break;

        default:
            break;
    }

}

//do some stuff in C with the data, 


//return the data to python
int total_bytes = 8*544

int cwInd = 0;
while(cwInd<(total_bytes))
{
    switch (bytesPerItem)
    {
        case 1:
            itemC = *(*(data)+cwInd); //return multi-dimensional array...
            break;  
        default:
            break;
    }
    itemObj = PyLong_FromUnsignedLong(itemC);
    if (!itemObj)
    {
        return NULL;
    }
    Py_INCREF(itemObj);
    PyList_Append(data_out, itemObj);
    {
        Py_DECREF(itemObj);
    }
    cwInd += bytesPerItem;
}
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------




Py_DECREF(data_out);
Py_DECREF(data_in);

Py_INCREF(Py_True);
return Py_True;
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I'm more of a hardware guy, so this stuff is all new to me.

Comment: What *exact* issue[s] are you running into? We need more information to help.

Comment: It would help a lot if you could indent the code properly.

Comment: Every time the program runs, it takes up more and more memory, eventually reaching a higher number than my ram and breaking.

Comment: Every time the *program* runs? All memory is freed after the process exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You leaked a reference to a `PyLong` here (and since it's in a loop, you leak quite a number of references to `PyLong`s):

```
itemObj = PyLong_FromUnsignedLong(itemC);
if (!itemObj)
{
    return NULL;
}
Py_INCREF(itemObj);
PyList_Append(data_out, itemObj);
{
    Py_DECREF(itemObj);
}
cwInd += bytesPerItem;
```

In the first line, you get a fresh reference to a `PyLong`; you then `INCREF` it, append it to a `list` (and unlike other `PyList` methods like the index get and set methods, `PyList_Append` does not steal a reference to the item, so the list has its own reference), then you `DECREF` (undoing the `INCREF`). But the original reference that `PyLong_FromUnsignedLong` gave you was never `DECREF`-ed away, and you replace that reference on the next loop, so you leak the `int`/`long`; it's not a complete leak until the list you created goes away (removing the last accessible reference to the `int`/`long`), but the reference counter is off-by-one as soon as the loop reassigns `itemobj` on the next go around is leaked immediately.